# Get and output the source of html using PHP ( shoutcast 7.html )

Tags: php, html

Hello I'm looking to grab some html and display it on another page. I'm doing a shoutcast server and I want to grab the song title from 7.html but all I need is the title of the song. Just a note I have tried fsockopen but my webhost blocks this so I cannot connect and grab the song title like that.

the source of the html looks like this

```
<HTML><meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache"></head><body>0,1,0,5000,0,96,SONG TITLE HERE</body></html>
```

All I need to display is "SONG TITLE HERE" How would I go about setting only that information as a php variable

I know of the method below but the issue here is that it will get everything. I only need a part of the source html.

```
<?php
$homepage = file_get_contents('http://www.example.com/');
echo $homepage;
?>
```

Comment: you could try doing `file_get_contents()` and then use a regex to extract the song information also i.e. `preg_match()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<?php
    $doc = new DOMDocument;
    $doc->loadhtmlfile('http://www.example.com/');

    $body = $doc->getElementsByTagName('body');
    $content = $body->item(0)->textContent;

    $arr = explode(',', $content);

    $song = end($arr);
?>
```

Comment: This will work, But my host will not let me load the off site html file. I get an "failed to open stream: Connection refused" I'm starting to think I may not be able to do this. Any one have an idea for a work around?

Comment: If this or file_get_contents does'nt work, looking at cURL or other options probably won't work either. You'll have to contact your host and ask them to remove whatever is blocking the request, or get another host.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
<?php
$content = file_get_contenst("7.html");
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($content);

$body = $dom->getElementsByTagName('body');

$info = $body->item(0)->nodeValue;

$infoArr = str_getcsv($info);

$title = array_pop($infoArr);
?>
```

There's lots of ways to handle this. You could also use something like this:

```
preg_match("/<body>(.*?)<\/body>/i", $html, $matches);
```

Instead of DOMDocument. Or explode() instead of str_getcsv().

Answer (score 0):

I was able to use iframe to get everything from the server's 7.html

adeneo answer would have worked perfect, however my Host didn't let me connect to other server in that way.